# chron write to string and back

Tags: r

(New to R, and coming from the world of pandas)

Assuming I have a column of chron objects in my data frame, how is it that I might be able to write them to csv in the right format, such that when I read back the csv, I can convert the same column back into chron objects as easily as `pandas.to_datetime(df.dt_col)`?

```
> x = chron("10/19/15", "22:11:22")
> x
[1] (10/19/15 22:11:22)
> as.character(x)
[1] "(10/19/15 22:11:22)"
> as.chron(as.character(x))
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: I'm curious: why are you using `chron` instead of `POSIXct`?

Comment: I don't really require tz, so I went with chron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're serializing a specific binary object to a CSV so you need to modify the workflow a bit:

```
library(chron)

dat <- data.frame(x=chron("10/19/15", "22:11:22"))

write.csv(data.frame(date=as.character(dates(dat$x)),
                     time=as.character(times(dat$x))), 
          file="chron.csv", row.names=FALSE)

new_dat <- read.csv("chron.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
new_dat$x <- chron(new_dat$date, new_dat$time)
```

However, what problem are you trying to solve? This might be better served as an Rdata file vs a CSV if you can give us a bit more info.

Comment: I need the output to be readable. I just want to read and write time objects easily. Is it necessary that I have to split the objects into separate date and time str columns, then consciously reapply back into a chron object when reading?

Answer (score 0):

Try `as.chron(as.character(x),format = "(%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`. Perhaps this does the job?
By using the R-help `?as.chron()` you can see what arguments the function takes and how to use them properly.